# Return value from loop expression with break

Tags: rust, break

Example 1

```
fn five() -> i32 {
    5   // ; not allowed I understand why
}

fn main() {
    let x = five();
    println!("The value of x is: {x}");
}
```

Example 2 (from https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch03-05-control-flow.html)

```
fn main() {
    let mut counter = 0;

    let result = loop {
        counter += 1;

        if counter == 10 {
            break counter * 2;
        }
    };
    println!("The result is {result}");
}
```

I understand why in Example 1 it must be `5` and not `5;`, but I am confused with Example 2, and have a few questions.

###### Question 1:

Why do we have `;` here? It will work without `;`, so why is it there? Is it some Rust convention or is there some technical reason?

###### Question 2:

If I do `break; counter * 2;` it will not return a value. What is the difference between `break; counter * 2;` and `break counter * 2;`?
Why does the second one work?

###### Question 3:

If I do:

```
break counter * 2
println!("After break");
```

compile error is: error: expected `;`, found `println`
If I do:

```
break counter * 2;
println!("After break");
```

there is no more compile error, but:

```
15 |             println!("After break");
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unreachable statement
```

But at least I understand this.
What I do not understand is why the `break counter * 2` is working fine but if I add something after it we have compile error.

To be honest, I am confused with this Example 2 my understanding is that if we want to return value from expression last line should be without ";" (like in Example 1), but clearly Example 2 proves otherwise.

Comment: Additionally to the answers I'd suggest keeping The Rust Reference in a next tab open. It has a good amount of information about the language https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/statements-and-expressions.html Though it doesn't mention `break` is diverging.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rust is a very expression-oriented language. And expressions, crucially, return values. When you write a function, you're writing an expression. That expression can consist of several *statements* separated by semicolons.

This is where Rust diverges from most other C-derived languages. Expressions are the driver in Rust, and semicolons *separate* statements. So a valid expression is `{ a ; b ; c ; d }`, where `d` is the eventual result. `a`, `b`, and `c` are mere side effects. In C, by contrast, a function is a sequence of statements terminated by semicolons, and statements *contain* expressions. So in C, a function body might look like `{ a ; b ; c ; d ; }`, where each statement is executed for side effects, and one of them *might* happen to be a `return` statement, but it's still a statement.

If a sequence of expressions in Rust *ends* in a semicolon, Rust assumes you meant to insert an extra `()` as the end, so `{ a ; b ; c ; d ; }` translates to `{ a ; b ; c ; d ; () }`. This is why we don't have to write `()` at the end of all of our unit-returning functions. It's just the default.

It's a more functional way of looking at things. A function returns a value, and whatever else happens is a side effect. The "usual" return value at the end of a function is simply that value, as an expression.

Now, because Rust supports a more imperative style (and because it's often useful and convenient), Rust also supports statements such as `break` and `return`, which break out of the usual flow of control early. These are *statements*. They have side effects which happen to return values, but they are not the "usual" return value of the expression.

```
let result = loop {
  counter += 1;
  if counter == 10 {
    break counter * 2;
  }
};
```

The inside of the `loop`, like most things in Rust, is an expression. So it can return a value. That value is ignored, since the loop is just going to run again. In this case, the block is equivalent to

```
let result = loop {
  counter += 1;
  if counter == 10 {
    break counter * 2;
    ()
  } else {
    () // 'if' can also insert () in the else block when used as an expression
  }
};
```

and we return `()` explicitly. If you remove the semicolon, you get

```
let result = loop {
  counter += 1;
  if counter == 10 {
    break counter * 2
  } else {
    () // 'if' can also insert () in the else block when used as an expression
  }
};
```

`break`, as an expression, "returns" a value as well. That value is of the diverging type, called [`never` or `!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html). Since `break` is guaranteed to diverge (i.e. to exit the usual flow of control), it returns `!`, which is the *only* type in Rust that is compatible with every other type. So the result of this `if` expression is still `()`, since `!` can convert to `()`. This is all moot, of course, since the `loop` will just run again if not broken, but that's what Rust is reasoning about internally.

In summary, you're not trying to return from the last line of the `{ ... }` block of the loop. You're trying to break out of the loop, which is *not* a normal return; it breaks the usual rules that the loop would follow, so it needs a special statement, and *statements* in Rust are separated from one another by a semicolon. The fact that you can *end* the statement sequence without a semicolon is incidental here, since `loop` ignores its block's result anyway.

Comment: This is a wonderful explanation. When I read the questions I thought I knew the answers but then I read the answers by Silvio and I definitely learnt quite a few things from them myself. Just let me add that `loop` is the only loop where a `break` expression can return a value.

Comment: And the reason is that `loop` is the only loop which is guaranteed to execute at least once.

Comment: @Cerberus Not quite; `loop` is the only loop which is guaranteed _not to exit except by `break`_ so the type of the loop value can be controlled by the `break`. “At least once” wouldn't help if it exited on a non-`break` condition after the first one.

Comment: A wonderful answer. One small nit: technically, `if expr { stmt; }` is _not_ like `if expr { stmt; () } else { () }`. The former can be chained in statements (`stmt; if expr { stmt; } stmt;`) without a trailing semicolon, while the latter can't. Internally, expressions are divided into "needs trailing semicolon" and "doesn't need" (and I think this is actually "needs", "accepts" and "rejects" but I'm unsure). `if` that does not end with a trailing expression does not need a trailing semicolon, and thus it is more of a standalone statements. Can be easier to view this as you explained :)

Answer (score -3):

> Question 1: Why do we have ; here? It will work without ;, so why is
> it there? It it some Rust convention or there is some technical
> reason?

If you are talking about `break counter * 2;`, then `;` is required because its not the last code in that function. If it was the last code in that function.
If it was the last code, like in this example, you can omit the semicolon.
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: OP could also omit the semicolon in their example, that's why they ask, also `rustfmt` would insert a semicolon in your example, too.